# C# formatting a decimal value to places of decimal

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

I need to format decimal numbers (serializing them as a string) that have a different number of digits after the decimal place.

Basically I want to remove all trailing zeros after the decimal point, except  always leaving at least 2 digits regardless of their numbers. So:

```
134.0000120 -> 134.000012
0.01000 -> 0.01
34.0000 -> 34.00
Etc.
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: I hadn't seen this thanks. I'll check if it works with doubles...

Comment: It will, but I would use `"0.00##############"` since a double can have 16 digits of precision.